# Why after storing data in variable I am getting undefined in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing a program in which I am trying to create a service and declare a variale in service and then creating a get() method in service to print the variable by calling the service method from component but I am getting undefined. Why?

## AppComponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent {


  }

}
```

## AppComponent.html

```
<app-comp1></app-comp1>
```

## Comp1Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AService } from 'src/app/services/a.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp1',
  templateUrl: './comp1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp1.component.css']
})
export class Comp1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private aService:AService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.aService.getFunc1();
  }

}
```

## AService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AService {

  private a;


  constructor() { }

  public func1():void
  {
    this.a=11;

  }


  public getFunc1()
  {
    console.log(this.a);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting undefined for?

Comment: Declare a as : a : number = 11 in service.

Answer (score 1):

From this code you never called `func1()` there for the variable held in the service never gets assigned. Before the `getfunc()` you would need to call the other function. So it would be

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.aService.func1() 
    this.aService.getFunc1()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the service in your module. (Or you can add it as provider to the component. )

```
@NgModule({

  ...
  providers: [AService,...],
  ...
})
```

Comment: Did you add the @Injectable() at the top 

```@Injectable()
export class AService{```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting `undefined` on the service.
You have to provide the service as Injectable to the app. One way to do that will be tomar service like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AService {
//service body
}
```

If the service needs to be scope at the module level, you can change the `providedIn: 'module'`

Read more on the angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/providers